# UILabel never gets initialized in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have a UILabel in interface builder that I've connected to a property, but it's staying nil through the viewDidLoad on that view controller. I've been stepping through and as soon as the DetailViewController is initialized, the label property is there but it is nil and it never seems to be initialized.

It was working until I switched from using segues to doing pushViewController on the navigation controller.

```
// DetailsViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TLitem.h"

@interface DetailsViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) TLitem *entry;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *entryLabel;

@end
```

Then in a table view in another view controller:

```
// EntryListViewController.m

DetailsViewController *details = [[DetailsViewController alloc] init];
[details setEntry:entry];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:details animated:YES];
```

And in the viewDidLoad:

```
// DetailsViewController.m
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    TLitem *entry = [self entry];
    UILabel *label = [self entryLabel];

    label.text = [entry valueForKey:@"text"];
```

Comment: You mention you changed from segues to programmatically pushing your view controller. Show us the code where you instantiate it.

Comment: If your view controller's view and the label in question are defined in a storyboard, you should instantiate it form the `UIStoryboard` instance.

Comment: Instantiate the view controller? It's the first line in NewEntryListViewController.m, above.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. But as I thought, the answer below by Jeffrey Thomas  should solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[[DetailsViewController alloc] init]` is not loading the view controller from the storyboard. It creates a new `DetailsViewController`, but nothing from IB will be connected. Look into `-instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`

It will look something like

```
DetailsViewController *details = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Some Storyboard Identifier You Create"];
details.entry = entry;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:details animated:YES];
```

Comment: This. all the info pertaining to outlet connections, etc. is in the storyboard. Storyboard-based view controllers are instantiated with `-initWithCoder:`.

Comment: Thank you!
self.storyboard is nil, and says it's a read-only property. Is there somewhere to set the storyboard for the whole app?
(Edit - pressed enter too early).

Comment: @thisAnneM No. Every view controller must be created with the storyboard of it's creator (or `+storyboardWithName:`). How id you instantiate `NewEntryListViewController`?

Comment: @JefferyThomas (I updated the filename - it is actually EntryListViewController).
    
    `EntryListTableViewController *entryList = [[EntryListTableViewController alloc] init];`
That file had no IBOutlets, which is why I got away with it. It in turn is created by the initial view controller. So do I refer to the Main Storyboard file in the initial view controller and then use `+storyboardWithName` each time I instantiate a new view controller?

Comment: @JefferyThomas - I changed that to `EntryListTableViewController *entryList = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EntryList"]` so each successive view is instantiated with the storyboard and that fixed everything. Thanks so much :)